# (Spark auto-recovery) how to re-launch slave when it's crashed by submitted job?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a question want to ask for help.
My spark structure: 1 master, 2 slaves.
I have a stream job deploy from master to two slaves, then one executor run this task the other pending.

#### Goal

Due to my job often meets OOM problem, so I want my slaves takeover to execute this job.

#### Problem

When one slave crashes, its status always LAUNCHING, so I have to re-run `./start-slave.sh` to recover it, but it's not a smart way to solve it I think, so

I want to automatically re-launch slave when it's crashed by submitted job.